# Removing a glimpse of purple screen at starting up of my pc

Tags: boot, startup, login-screen

I have edited the log in screen and log in animation through plymouth. I prefer a total black screen or simillar theme. Everything is ok for now but when I hit enter after giving my password in the log in screen, a purple screen comes up for about 1 or 1/2 second, just before going to my desktop. I have searched and looked into a lot of file and now i am just exhausted, do anyone have any idea where I can get the file to change the color code or something like that?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1127236/739431

Comment: will it replace my current theme or any other customizations?

Comment: if you change desktop session.. its entirely different.. yes you will not have even similar look of the default session that is Ubuntu..

Comment: you can try it without fear.. if you are not satisfied just use the default session at login..